# How to repent for copyright infringment

Tags: tawba, fatwa, fatwa-explanation, property

Since i was a child and introduced to the internet,i have watched cartoons, movies anime ,read manga and downloaded games from internet i am 19 and found out about copyright in islam a month or two ago. I didn't know it was haram .

. What do i do after asking forgiveness from Allah Talah , Do i have to pay for this since i didn't hack and only viewed and downloaded what was already shared online . If i have to pay to whom .How do you pay to or donate to these big companies.I don't even remember all  of what i have watched and from where .Does anyone have any idea what i should do.any fatwa or am i not liable since i didn't directly take anything and wouldn't have ,if i knew it was stealing.